# editing a data in a datatable using a modal form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a datatable, each row has a

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="edit-promo-img" action="#{branchController.prepareEdit}" value="" oncomplete="updateBranchForm()"/>
```

this is my modal:

```
<div id="edit-branch-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <h:form id="editBranchForm">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            Branch Details
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateBranchLabel_name}" for="name" /></div>
            <div><h:inputText id="name" value="#{branchController.selected.name}" title="#{bundle.CreateBranchTitle_name}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateBranchRequiredMessage_name}"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <p:commandButton action="#{branchController.update}" value="#{bundle.CreateBranchSaveLink}" />
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <p:remoteCommand name="updateBranchForm" update="@form" />
    </h:form>
```

prepareEdit method:

```
public void prepareEdit() {
    current = (Branch) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
}
```

selected method:

```
public Branch getSelected() {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new Branch();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return current;
}
```

when i debugged on the getSelected method, there is actually correct data on my "current" object.

my problem is, the input in the modal has no data.

using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces and my bean is using ViewScope.

Comment: So you have your value into the `current` variable but when `getSelected()` is executed it is null? Check your whole bean is not being rebuilt during the request.

Comment: At what point do you ajax-update the modal dialog to reflect new values?

Comment: @XtremeBiker the value inside the input is null but when i debug getSelected, it has a value.

Comment: @kolossus on clicking the edit button

Comment: So I guess your backing bean is not maintaining `current` variable value for some reason. Check all the parts this value is being overwritten. Check bean's constructor to ensure your bean is not being rebuilt.

Comment: instead of `<h:inputText id="name" value="#{branchController.selected.name}">` i changed it to outputText with the same value `value="#{branchController.selected.name}">` and correct value is displayed.. i dont get it why inputText doesnt work while outputText does.